# Change file association programmatically without ftype/assoc

Tags: windows, command-line, shell-script

From batch the pair `ftype`+`assoc` works fine:

```
ftype my_file_txt=C:\Windows\notepad.exe "%%1"
assoc .txt=my_file_txt
```

But from JScript/CScript/WScript it can't be done because these are virtual commands existng within cmd.exe only.

**Question**: how to change file association another way?

I can exec a special .bat file probably, but this is undesirable (if there is a cleaner way).

Windows 7 x64

Comment: Then run the command like this `cmd.exe /c ftype`

Comment: Or do the registry changes yourself.